# VTP transparent mode Switch does not pass user traffic to and from other VTP Switches

Tags: vlan, vtp

Practicing on Packet Tracer, I have a topology of four switches named Switch-A, B, C and D. connected with one another in straight line
Switch A has two VLANs (Faculty and Students) and is configured as VTP Server
Switch B is VTP Client, it gets VLAN from VTP Server syned. OK
Switch C is in VTP Transparent mode. No VLANS exists here except VLAN 1 default.
Switch D is VTP Client and it does get synced with VTP Server OK.

PC1 is on Switch-A VLAN Faculty, PC3 is on Switch-B VLAN Faculty, PC10 is on Switch-D VLAN Faculty

I can Ping from PC1 to PC3 fine and vice versa but can't get ping from PC1 to PC10 or vice verssa. because of the switch C which is VTP tranparent. The moment I change it to VTP client, Ping get success.

Question is will a VTP transparent switch block VLAN traffic to and from other VTP switches? why is that?
[image: CISCO PACET TRACER VLAN VTP]

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with VTP.

If Switch C only has VLAN 1, it's not going to forward other tagged traffic from one port to another.

Comment: Yes Switch-C has only VLAN-1 (being VTP Transparent) it will pass VTP updates to Switch-D (VTP Client) But why Switch-C not pass on other VLAN traffic from Switch-B to Switch-D. If not then what setup should be there to achieve this?

Comment: If switch C is in VTP transparent mode, you will need to manually create the VLANs on switch C.  “Transparent” mode only refers to the VTP protocol itself, not to VLAN traffic.

Comment: In the case when transparent switch needs to have those VLANs manually created which are on VTP client and VTP server, what is the real benefit for VTP transparent? I suppose VTP transparent while it must not take part in any VLAN stuff but still be able to pass on other VLANs traffic. If that's the requirement that way, how to pass other VLAN traffic through transparent switch?

Comment: Again, don't confuse VTP protocol with forwarding tagged traffic.  VTP transparent simply ignores the VTP protocol.  That may or may not be an advantage, depending on your design.  You don't always want all VLANs everywhere.